# XMLHttpRequest is not working for Json

Tags: html, json, xmlhttprequest, xmlhttprequest-level2, xmlhttprequest-states

Am very new to JSON. So read some topics on w3schools and tried to execute locally but its not working. Kindly anyone help me to overcome this issue.

Note:
1) Kept 1.html and myTutorials.txt files in same directory.
2) I debugged the html code and found that "xmlhttp.status" is always zero.
3) But same code in w3schools website is working fine.
Links:

i)  http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_http.asp    -->   1.html
ii)  http://www.w3schools.com/json/myTutorials.txt  -->    myTutorials.txt

### My Html code: 1.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "myTutorials.txt";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + 
        arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

### The below contents are from "myTutorials.txt" file.

```html
[
{
"display": "HTML Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "CSS Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "JavaScript Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "jQuery Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "JSON Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "AJAX Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "SQL Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "PHP Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp"
},
{
"display": "XML Tutorial",
"url": "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp"
}
]
```

---

Comment: Did you run this from the web or from file system?

Comment: are you using `http(s)://` or `file://` protocol

Comment: Hi, i checked the same 1.html in chrome and firefox but its not working. And for debugging i tried like "var url = "myTutorials.txt";"

Comment: Please answer the question. You cannot run Ajax from file:// protocol

Comment: Hi, i checked the same 1.html in chrome and firefox but its not working. And for debugging i tried like                         "var url = "myTutorials.txt";  (or) var url = "file:///D:/pract/myTutorials.txt"; but didnt worked. I kept 1.html and myTutorials.txt file in "D:\pract"

Answer (score 1):

The reason XMLHttpRequest doesn't work because you're using file:// protocol to open the html file. The XMLHttpRequest object is used to exchange data with a server behind the scenes. When trying to do a HTTP request using XMLHttpRequest from a local file, it basically fails due to Access-Control-Allow-Origin violation. So what you need to do is to host the html file and text file in a web server and then access the html file using http protocol i.e. enter the url of html page in web browser like:   http://www.example.com/1.html.